# configuring springXD Horthonworks

Tags: spring-xd

I try to Configuring Spring XD to use Hadoop (horthonworks) but when I excute this line  In a terminal "./xd-singlenode --hadoopDistro hadoop11" ,I get error 'hadoop11' is not a valid value for option --hadoopDistro Possible values are [cdh5, hdp22, phd21, hadoop27, phd30]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, the Spring Xd version your are trying to use is wrong. For horthonworks configuration you should use hdp22.

Regards